# Weird GAS ARM syntax

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu-assembler

When I disassembled my arm elf .so file, I saw the following code:

```
 170c:  e28fc600    add ip, pc, #0, 12
```

I only know it is an ARM "add" instruction.
But from the ARM reference manual "add" has a syntax like:

```
op{S}{cond} {Rd}, Rn, Operand2

op{cond} {Rd}, Rn, #imm12               ; Thumb-2 ADD and SUB only
```

and Operand2 is:

```
  #constant
  Rm {, shift}
```

This line of asm should fall down into the syntax:

```
  op Rd, Rn, #constant
```

So, the code should means,
"add pc and #0 to ip"

Then the question is:

1. What about the last part of the code ", 12"?
2. Where did you find these information, GAS manual or ARM manual?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a part of code which will be changed at link time.

The 12 in the encoding says that the immediate will be right rotated by 12 bits. Obviously that currently does not make sense for a #0. Also the whole opcode is currently nothing more than a fancy

```
mov ip, pc
```

Have a look at the code during runtime, probably the #0 changed into something which makes more sense.

The numbers never lie.

`e28fc600`

**Nibbles**

1. `e` always
2. `28` add immediate with no condition codes set.
3. `f` *Rb* is the `pc` or `R15`.
4. `c` *Rd* is the `ip` or `R12`.
5. `600` are the shifter ops or *zero rotated by* **6*2** .

As the instruction is rather *bizzare* the disassembled output maybe abnormal; normally just the constant is displayed *#0xef00* as nobody cares how it is encoded.  Also, as this is a *shared library*, the instruction maybe fixed up via a relocation at run time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But where do you get this syntax information?

Comment: It's from the arm architecture reference manual (ARM ARM). According to your original question you already have one. If you check out the ADD-Instruction for ARM (not thumb or thumb2) you'll find the encoding. The #imm12 is encoded in the bottom 12 bits and results in a final value of result = RotateRight(bits[7:0], [12:8]*2).

Comment: I know the means of #imm12. I am just wondering why "add ip, pc, #0, 12" means right rotate #0 by 12. Why not "add ip, pc, #0 ROR 12 ?

Comment: Then that's the question you should have asked in your original post. @Masta79 gave you what you asked for. Perhaps you should reformulate the question and ask again.

Comment: @artless noise Thanks for the addition.

Comment: @artless noise, Thanks a lot. Joe Hass, thanks for your reminding.